# Facebook share is not working on published app - Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've a strange issue on my android app. I've an approved Facebook with publish_actions. It works very well if I try within a signed APK. But after I'm publishing my app on Playstore and install the App from Playstore, publishing is not working somehow. Is there a special configuration before sending APK to Playstore? (Hashkey and other params are fine and works if I install APK directly to my phone.)

**UPDATE**

If I deinstall the Facebook App on my phone, share works also fine. Btw: I am trying to post an image and a link.